# Do cookies expire on the server side or on the client/browser side?

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, web, http-headers

I know that if i login to a website, i get `set-cookie` headers with `max-age/expires values`, that tell when these cookies expire. Now what i want to know is, do these cookies expire on the `client side`? so the browser gets rid of them, **OR** on the `server side` so the server blocks/deletes them? i'm asking to see if it is possible for someone to extend the age of cookies using something like `fiddler/charlesProxy`.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies on client side have expiry date and time value associated with it. After the specified date & time, browser will not honour that cookie and will skip that cookie in further HTTP(s) requests.

*i'm asking to see if it is possible for someone to extend the age of cookies using something like fiddler/charlesProxy*

a. If we tamper HTTP request, cookie will reach the server. (We can achieve this using fiddler/charlesProxy)

b. Alternatively, If we tamper the expiry date in browser cache, browser will start honouring it again. (We can achieve this using browser cookie editor e.g [Advanced Cookie Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-manager/))

Conclusion: We can't trust cookie’s value for time sensitive tasks. 
For example, session id will have timestamp associated with it only in encrypted format so that people can’t tamper it.